# CKEditor 5 online builder is not working in React project

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

I use CKEditor 5 online builder to **insert the CKEditor to a Gatsby site**, after npm start, the CKEditor looks like **all disabled status**, like below image:

[Screenshot for CKEditor in Gatsby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss7I7.png)

You also can use below sandbox to check **my code**: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-benz-wqjoj4?file=/src/components/Text.jsx

Can't I use **CKEditor 5 online builder** in Gatsby project? I just want to use most easiest way refer from: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html

Do I need config by myself or anything I missed?

Answer (score 1):

OK, finally, our arch to help me fix this issue.
Use "**gatsby-plugin-babel-exclude**", to exclude ckeditor from babel loader, the code will like below:

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-babel-exclude',
  options: {
    exclude: require.resolve('ckeditor5-custom-build'),
  },
},
```